# IllegalArgumentException - Parameter with that name [name] did not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wicket

I have a this query on my code:

```
return Long.parseLong(getEntityManager().createQuery(
"SELECT COUNT(a) FROM ApartmentExtraType a WHERE a.accommodation.id = :idacc AND (LOWER(a.name) LIKE :name)", 
Long.class)
.setParameter("idacc", accommodation.getId())
.setParameter("name", "%" + filterQuery.getFieldFilter("name").toString().toLowerCase() + "%")
getSingleResult().toString());
```

If the query don't find any element i have no problem, but if it found at least one element I have this error:

```
Last cause: Parameter with that name [name] did not exist WicketMessage: Error attaching this container for rendering: 
[WebMarkupContainer [Component id = tbody]]
```

The name of the relative column is "name" and I'm sure. Other query seems to be identical to this one and they work fine. I don't know which is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is not with the column name it is with the parameter you are passing in called "name." The "idacc" one looks like it was grabbed correctly.

So this part is not working

> `filterQuery.getFieldFilter("name").toString().toLowerCase()`

Try passing in a String and see if that works something like

> `.setParameter("name", "ExampleName");`

If that runs fine then there is something wrong with the `getFieldFilter` function

Comment: I controlled if the problem was the getFieldFilter but I don't think so because the syste.out print the right string.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved. The problem was that the query is composed in different method because it vary depending on user's input and in one of this method a variable was badly instantiated. So the JVM didn't find the part of the query with the [name] parameter.